# O link de reconfiguração de senha não chega clicável no email do usuario

Tags: php

Problema: email enviado para resetar senha, chega com link NAO CLICÁVEL. Acredito que tem algo errado na variável da URL.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['reset-request-submit'])) {

  $selector = bin2hex(random_bytes(8));
  $token = random_bytes(32);
  $url = "www.wonline.com.br/create-new-password.php?selector=" . $selector . "&validator=" . bin2hex($token);
  $expires = date("U") + 1800;
 
  $to = $userEmail;
  $subject = 'Redefina a sua senha';
  $message = '<p>Nós recebemos sua solicitação de Reconfigurar a senha. Use o link de reconfiguraçao abaixo. ';
  $message .= 'Se não foi você quem solicitou, ignore este email</p>';
  $message .= '<p>Aqui está o seu link de redefiniçao de senha:</p></br>';
  $message .= '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>';
  $headers = "From: <web@gmail.com>\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: user@gmail.com\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  header("Location: ../reset-password.php?reset=success");
} else {
  header("Location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua mensagem estiver de fato chegando em "HTML" é provavel que o cliente de email não aceite o link sem HTTP, porque pensa que é uma tentativa de redirecionar para algo interno do cliente de email, então adicione o protocolo de link "HTTP", algo como:

```
$url = "http://www.quae.com.br/create-new-password.php?selector=" . $selector . "&validator=" . bin2hex($token);
```

Ou (disso "OU" e não "E") então no link diretamente:

```
$message .= '<a href="http://' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>';
```

Mas não há garantia de que funcione, porque depende do cliente de email, gmail, outlook, thunderbird, etc, se estiver bloqueado para links só vai depender da pessoa copiar e colar então.

Comment: PERFEITO! Resolveu a questão! Era só isso mesmo! Testei no meu email yahoo. Vou testar agora em gmail e outros. Valeu demais!

Comment: Funcionou com Gmail tambem! Ótimo! Era isso mesmo! Obrigado! Esqueci de mencionar que usei a opção 1 que foi dada: $url = colocando o http na frente.